# flutter doesn't show images in the web

Tags: image, flutter, web

Hello i have build a flutter web project which includes some images but all without one aren't shown in the web but all are shown in the emulator. Could you tell me the solution for this?
Tell me if you need more insides.

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: nanostifel
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
CFBundleVersion.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter


cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter:
uses-material-design: true
assets:[enter image description here][1]
- images/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [migration guide for Flutter Web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/docs/migration_guide.md#webassets-optional) you will see that: **If the application has assets, they need to be in the web/assets directory. You may also have to update paths within your source code that reference these assets.**

But for the latest versions of Flutter you can have the assets directory in the root of your project too.

So check this steps:

1. Put your assets in the in the folder `web/assets` of your project.
2. You don't need to specify the name of the assets in your pubspec.yaml
3. To use it in a a widget, you don't need to use all the path, use only the file name, for example if you have the image `web/assets/myImage.png` just use it as follows:

   `Image.asset('myImage.png')`

And if you are working with the latest version of Flutter, and you have your image in a folder `rootProject/assets/images/myImage.png` use it as follows:

```
Image.asset('images/myImage.png')
```

**In both cases is it necessary to have the images in a folder named `assets`**